# java- using a filter to check remote address

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

What would be the best approach to detect if a web application is accessed locally?
I am interested in checking this in a **filter** (`javax.servlet.Filter`).
I could check the `ServletRequest#getRemoteAddr()` if it is `127.0.0.1` but if it is running in a IPv6 machine, the address would be `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`.
Are there any other pitfalls I should be aware of, or if I just check for these 2 string patterns, I would be ok?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<strike>In theory, the following ought to be sufficient.</strike>

```
if (request.getRemoteAddr().equals(request.getLocalAddr())) {
    // Locally accessed.
} else {
    // Remotely accessed.
}
```

---

**Update** as per the comments, `request.getLocalAddr()` seems to return `0.0.0.0` which can indeed happen when the server is behind a proxy.

You may instead want to compare it against the addresses as resolved by [`InetAddress`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html).

```
private Set<String> localAddresses = new HashSet<String>(); 

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    try {
        localAddresses.add(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
        for (InetAddress inetAddress : InetAddress.getAllByName("localhost")) {
            localAddresses.add(inetAddress.getHostAddress());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ServletException("Unable to lookup local addresses");
    }
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (localAddresses.contains(request.getRemoteAddr())) {
        // Locally accessed.
    } else {
        // Remotely accessed.
    }
}
```

In my case, the `localAddresses` contains the following:

```
[192.168.1.101, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1]
```

Comment: Could we not have the case that the client IP is localhost and the server is other e.g. the public IP?

Comment: Then there's just means of remote access. Or isn't that what you're asking?

Comment: It seems this is not correct. The `request.getLocalAddr()` always returns `0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

You also need to check all other IP-addresses of your box like the one of your ethernet interfaces. Also consider aliases.

Comment: @Heico:You mean get all the registered interfaces for the machine? And then compare with remote address?

Comment: essentially. The network path through which the client connects with the server can include any of its active network interfaces, it doesn't have to be localhost.

Comment: I looped over all interfaces but the `127.0.0.1` is not among the set!

Answer (score 1):

Even if the client is running locally, it might not be using the loopback interface.  Odds are good that your machine will have an assigned IP address, and depending on /etc/hosts configuration, DNS configuration, etc. the IP address you connect to might not be the loopback address.

Assuming that you want to provide some sort of "enahanced" interface that is "more secure" because it originates on the same machine, beware that even loopback interfaces can be snooped upon by using tools like wireshark.  If this interface is meant to display data suitable for a more-trusted client, then odds are good you should take the efforts to do proper ssl tunneling via https.

Comment: The IP address the client connects to, might not be the loopback address.Ok.But the originating IP (i.e. IP of the client) will always be the loopback address. Right?

Comment: May be I missunderstand your answer.You are talking about the client?

Comment: When the client connects, it will have a return IP address.  There's little ability to control on the server side as to what the client identifies as it's return IP address.