# Getting Remote Host in jersey 2.4 grizzly http container

Tags: jersey

I'm using jersey 2.4 grizzly2-http container in my application and was wondering is there a way to get the Remote Host address inside a Request Filter. I would like to reject all requests that are not coming from a list of allowed remote IPs.

Thanks
Josip

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a servlet filter external to Jersey. This will be much more customizable. Tomcat has one natively, but you could always role your own. This way you can externalize this from your code and make changes in your web.xml without having to rebuild your app.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter

Here is a more generic one you could use with grizzly
[java- using a filter to check remote address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009426/java-using-a-filter-to-check-remote-address)