# What is the proper way to restrict a J2EE servlet to only be called from the localhost?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, localhost

I am working on building a servlet to perform work that should only be able to be initiated from the host itself.  My current plan is to check the request object in the service method:

```
public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
```

The only methods I see on `ServletRequest` that seem relevant are `getRemoteHost()` and `getRemoteAddr()`.  My biggest concerns are whether this could be spoofed (someone could send an inbound request with the source IP `127.0.0.1` and start the process) or if checking the IP against `127.0.0.1` could fail if IPv6 is being used.

There will be a credential which should prevent an IP spoof from being successful but I can't help but feel like there's a better, more direct way to check (or otherwise restrict) the source of the request.

Is there a standard way to reliably make this restriction that is independent of IP version and safe from spoofing (assuming an attacker could get the credential but not access to the server)?  I think from a security perspective the credential should be sufficient; I'm mostly interested in what the 'right' way to solve this problem is.

**EDIT:**

I don't believe this is a duplicate of [java- using a filter to check remote address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009426) as I was not considering using a filter in the first place.  While a filter-based solution was eventually what I went with this question is open to other potential solutions as well (for example, Raffaele's suggestion to use a server socket could prove useful to someone else or an answer that hasn't been posted yet could be superior to both methods).

Comment: If using Tomcat you could use [`RemoteAddrFilter`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/filters/RemoteAddrFilter.html).

Comment: Spoofing is a non-issue, since HTTP is TCP which requires negotiating to even establish a connection before sending the request. --- You're right, IPv6 localhost is different ([::1]), but you can just check both.

Comment: I would follow @BoristheSpider suggestion, except write your own filter so you're not dependent on Tomcat. This keeps the logic outside of your servlet, and even makes it reusable for other servlets, since the filter is *attached* to the servlet in the `web.xml` file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java- using a filter to check remote address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009426/java-using-a-filter-to-check-remote-address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Filters`:

```
class OnlyLocalhostFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (servletRequest.getLocalAddr().equals(servletRequest.getRemoteAddr())) {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

After that declare you filter `OnlyLocalhostFilter` in `web.xml` and bind it to servlet you want.

**UPDATE:**

This solution not always works right. Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009426/java-using-a-filter-to-check-remote-address)

Comment: This is overly simplistic. It will not work in the general case - 'localhost' is the resolved name for the local machine. You need to carry out a lookup on the IP of the request and see if that is localhost or the local machine hostname.

Comment: But it might be worth explaining that this naive example needs work before it can be put to use.

Comment: Just as a sanity check, wouldn't checking the result of `servletRequest.getLocalAddr()` as equal to either `127.0.0.1` or `::1` be a sufficient check?

Comment: @thesquaregroot , it can return you `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` . Updated the answer.

Comment: Good point, thank you!  I would assume checking against those should be sufficient though since a request with that local address could only have gotten there from a process on the same host, right?

Comment: @ka4eli The updated answer makes a ton of sense.  So long as it's consistent with how it returns the IPs (I don't see why it wouldn't be) this should cover all the bases with very straightforward logic (if the source is the destination it must be localhost).

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to solve this is not to act at the servlet (application) level, but instead bind your entire server socket on `127.0.0.1` (or another loopback address).

I think the default API for Java server socket uses `0.0.0.0` which is *anyaddress*, but if you specify a loopback address like `127.0.0.1` (or `localhost`) your application is protected at the kernel level.

Comment: That's if **all** the services are bound to localhost. Using a combination of vhosts and separate applications one could bind one some _applications_ to localhost. But in any case, this approach does not allow for restricting access to a **servlet** to localhost.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is pretty clear from my answer too, but thanks for pointing it out. There's nothing wrong in whitelisting allowed source IPs, but for OP requirement I think this solution is easier and more elegant, even if not a translation word-for-word of the original question. The interface could even be passed as a startup parameter

Comment: I suppose I could have the servlet `init()` method (or some other JVM initialization trigger) create a `ServerSocket` and bind it to `127.0.0.1` on some port to listen for requests for this.  It seems a bit roundabout but it might work.  Is there a way to start a `ServerSocket` directly on JVM start?  Also, does this do anything to work around spoofing or is that just a fact of life that I'll have to deal with?

Comment: @thesquaregroot you cannot spoof a request in the way you think. The IP address is the remote IP of the sender because they presumably want their response back! Spoofing does not work in that way and in fact the TCP/IP stack is build to prevent such silliness.

Comment: The address must be passed to the server (Tomcat, Jetty, Glassfish): servlets should not know it. The destination IP can't be *spoofed*

Comment: @Raffaele Ah, that makes sense.  I was thinking of checking the source IP not the destination.  So long as the destination is `127.0.0.1` (or the IPv6 equivalent) I should be good.  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I suggest you bind on `localhost` so that it's resolved the same way by the server and by the browser on the same system