# How to do that service wriiten in java can handle requests only from the defined ip?

Tags: java, http, server, endpoint

I want to write application in java that consists of few endpoints. I want that this endpoints handle requests only if They are sent from defined ip. How can I implement it?

Comment: In theory, you can handle this in the filter ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009426/java-using-a-filter-to-check-remote-address)), but in practice by the time the request hits your servlet, the IP address may have changed.

Comment: How about you give us some insight on your code. It's easier for us to help you if we don't have to start from scratch.

Comment: That depends on what you are using to implement your webservices/endpoints. If you have a webserver like Apache or Nginx in between the client and your services you could define the ip restrictions there (I'd not hardcode those into the application anyways since even "static" IP addresses can change from time to time)

Comment: Can you prompt me please How can I define ip of  a sender in the http protocol. What header or something else response for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this to get the IP address, that matches this address with your predefined IP addresses.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "startup", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ProcessResponse startUp(@RequestBody RequestTemplate requestTemplate, HttpServletRequest request) {

        System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());
        // some other code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Web Application**

Apache Tomcat

Edit the WEB-INF/web.xml file in the application. Add the following:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>allow</param-name>
    <param-value><!-- insert your ip list / regex here --></param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This instructs the filter to block all IP addresses except the ones included. The filter supports blocking only the IP addresses listed. More information on the filter can be found here.

**Spring Boot**

For Spring Boot applications that run with the embedded Apache Tomcat container, which is the default behavior, use the same filter described in the Apache Tomcat section above. It is configured in the code instead of XML. The Spring Boot document explains how to enable a Servlet Filter.  Use the instructions in the document to enable the RemoteAddrFilter.

Spring Boot Document : [Document](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter)